# nginx naxsi $URL_X doesn't work

Tags: nginx, firewall, regex

Recently recompiled my NGINX with a NAXSI module. Now setting up the white lists but the $URL_X functionality doesn't seem to work at all. Generating

> Incorrect line BasicRule wl:1312

in NGINX error logs every time I try it. Yet normal whitelisting works fine.

Here is an example of the failing rule:

```
BasicRule wl:1312 "mz:$URL_X:^/index/register/.*|URL";
```

Here is an example of one that works just fine, except it can't match the super long random string on the end of that url after /register/ bit that I need to whitelist:

```
BasicRule wl:1312 "mz:$URL:/index/register/|URL";
```

So normal string $URL works, but regex $URL_X functionality seem to be as if it is turned off...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following syntax:

```
BasicRule wl:1312 "mz:$URL_X:^/index/register/.*$|URL";
```

Comment: I'll give it a go when have the time available, at the moment I had to resort to modifying all of the default rules to stop them from filtering certain parts of document completely. There are other levels of security that protect us but still would like to get this working.